# Sed not pattern matching

Tags: regex, sed

I have a directory with these files in it:

```
abc12345abc
abc1234567abc
abc123456789abc
```

I want to grab the file that has 7 numerals in it. I need to do this using sed via the pipe. I thought this would work:

```
ls -l | sed -n '/[0-9]\{7\}/p'
```

It returns:

```
abc1234567abc
abc123456789abc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regular expressions aren't anchored. `abc123456789abc` has a string of exactly 7 digits, 3 of them in fact: `1234567`, `2345678`, and `3456789`. If you want the file names that don't have any longer matches, you need to check for non-digits before and after.

```
sed -n '/[^0-9][0-9]{7}[^0-9]/p'
```

Comment: Perhaps `sed -En '/[^0-9][0-9]{7}[^0-9]/p' file` or `sed -n '/[^0-9][0-9]\{7\}[^0-9]/p' file`? What if the file began/ended with 7 digits or only contained 7 digits?

Comment: Perhaps. The question suggests we don't need to be that general, though.

Comment: Please review your solution as to the first part of my comment.

Answer (score 1):

You want to match seven digits that are not enclosed with another digit.

You may use

```
sed -En '/(^|[^0-9])[0-9]{7}($|[^0-9])/p'
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/6l9Bzh).

**Details**

- `-E` - enables POSIX ERE syntax (now, there is no need to escape `{x}` interval quantifiers)
- `(^|[^0-9])` - start of string or a non-digit char
- `[0-9]{7}` - seven digits
- `($|[^0-9])` - end of string or a non-digit char.

Answer (score 1):

First rule of scripting, **don't parse ls**

If you are trying to match files in a directory, use `find`, that's what it's meant for

```
find dir/ -regextype posix-extended -type f \
   -regex ".*[^[:digit:]][[:digit:]]{7}[^[:digit:]].*"
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/[0-9]\{7\}/!d;/[0-9]\{8\}/d' file
```

If there are not 7 consecutive digits or there are more, delete the line.